# Substituir o csproj dá problemas?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Pela segunda vez meu `.csproj.user` foi detonado. Não sei porque isso tem acontecido ou o que pode influenciar nesse arquivo. Bem, esse é um projeto novo que fiz, usando o `.Net Standard`. Quando eu abro o `.csproj.user` eu tenho isso:

`NULLNULLNULLNULLNULLNULL...`. Tenho um outro projeto que foi deixado, mas o projeto Android está exatamente como o meu e o `.csproj.user` está assim.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SelectedDevice>Samsung SM-J500M</SelectedDevice>
    <DefaultDevice>VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone</DefaultDevice>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Agora, antes não havia o arquivo `.csproj`. Após baixar do TFS ele veio, em realidade os dois: `.csproj` e o `.csproj.user`. Sinceramente não sei porque desse último `.csproj.user` não sei o que ele faz e pra que serve. Mesmo baixando o `.csproj` meu projeto não roda, ele não é carregado e mesmo dando reload ele continua fora do projeto. O que posso fazer nesse sentido? É um projeto `Android` com `Xamarin.Forms` e projeto `.Net Standard`.

Comment: Tentei uma solução: Reescrevi o `.csproj.user` por um funcionando. Agora o Android está carregado, mas falta algumas coisas, entre eles o `MainActivity`. Posso copiar e colar o `MainActivity` na pasta do `Android`?

Comment: exclua o arquivo .csproj.user e reabra o projecto pelo .csproj do directorio do prejecto incorporado

Answer (score 0):

O arquivo `csproj` é um xml que guarda a estrutura de pastas, arquivos, referências e outras propriedades a relacionadas ao projeto em si.

O arquivo `csproj.user` até onde eu sei é gerado pelo visual studio e guarda algumas informações sobre o ambiente de desenvolvimento no visual studio mesmo, por exemplo: quais arquivos daquele projeto estão abertos em que tipo de editor e coisas desse tipo. Ou seja, ele é dispensável.

No visual studio a gente tem uma estrutura baseada em solution, que contém um ou mais projetos. O arquivo `sln` também é um xml com objetivos parecidos com o do `csproj`, mas nesse caso visando a solução. Por exemplo: quais projetos daquele diretório fazem parte da solução, quais deles estão marcados para build e deploy, seus perfis de configuração de execução, entre outras.

Para o seu problema, sugiro apagar a pasta `.vs` (Deve etar como pasta oculta no diretório da solução), os arquivos `.user` e deletar os diretórios `bin` e `obj` de todos os projetos. Então, inclui os projetos que estiverem de fora na solução novamente, faz um clean e rebuild all. deve haver algum cache com lixo.

Espero que ajude